# Does a French citizen living in the US owning stocks in a brokerage account in France have to pay taxes on dividends to the French tax authorities?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, international, france

Does a French citizen living in the United States and owning stocks in a brokerage account located in France have to pay taxes on dividends to the French tax authorities ([fisc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administration_fiscale))?

Additional information:

- The French citizen is a tax resident and permanent resident of the United States (The French citizen will subsequently have to pay [taxes on dividends](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/105931/5656) to the IRS in United States, within the limit of the double taxation rules).