# How can I distinguish ordinary dividend from qualified dividend for when reporting amounts related to foreign financial assets in Turbotax (US taxes)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, international, turbotax

How can I distinguish ordinary dividends from qualified dividends for when reporting amounts related to foreign financial assets (= hold in non-US brokerage accounts) on the Turbotax website when filing US taxes?

I don't see the option:

[image]

In response to comments/answers:

- A fair amount of non-US corporations have qualified dividends e.g. see [How to efficiently know which portion of the dividends are qualified dividends in a French brokerage account, from the United States' IRS standpoint?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/105931/5656)
- I use the Turbotax website, not the desktop program.

Comment: The question to ask is "Are there any Qualified Dividends from foreign assets?" to which I suspect the answer is No; Qualified Dividends are a subset of dividends paid by US corporations, and foreign dividends cannot be Qualified Dividends. Now, if those foreign assets are investments in domestic corporations, that's a different matter.

Comment: @DilipSarwate A fair amount of non-US corporations have qualified dividends e.g. see [How to efficiently know which portion of the dividends are qualified dividends in a French brokerage account, from the United States' IRS standpoint?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/105931/5656)

Comment: @DilipSarwate Instructions for 1099DIV say "If the foreign corporation does not meet either (1) or (2) above, then it may be treated as a qualified foreign corporation for any dividend paid by the corporation if the stock associated with the dividend paid is readily tradable on an established securities market in the United States." That changed with JGTRRA 2003 it seems.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that link was to a question of yours. This is a French brokerage account? I think that changes things and is a detail that may change the answers here. At this point I think you have enough chances for substantial error that it would be worth hiring professional help that has experience with foreign accounts.

Comment: @T.M. Why would the fact that it is a French brokerage account differ from is it were a non-US, non-French brokerage account?

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's French, but it I think does matter that it's an account held at a non US firm. I could be wrong about that, but the point is it's not a simple situation.

Comment: @T.M. That's correct: non-US brokerage accounts are treated differently from US brokerage accounts. E.g. from understanding one has to file one Form 8938 for each non-US brokerage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add a caveat to my answer that it wasn't clear before that this was from a foreign account. Various things such as citizenship, tax residence, etc could further affect the situation.

This appears to have the answer. 
https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3308138-how-do-i-report-foreign-dividends
Basically enter a 1099-div manually and choose I’ll enter it myself and put the amounts in box 1a and 1b

Comment: Do I have to report dividends on both "Amounts Related to Foreign Financial Assets" and 1099-div? I'm afraid that it will count twice. I use the Turbotax website and tried Googling the question. What other information do you need? In the link you mentioned, I'm not sure whether "foreign dividends" refer to  foreign corporation held in US brokerage account or a non-US brokerage account.

Comment: In the note there it states that you should also report in the appropriate income area on Turbotax. Also, make sure your account qualifies for what they are looking for there by clicking on their link "foreign financial assets". If it doesn't meet the definition there you wouldn't enter it here. What type of account is it? An account held at a US financial institution or a foreign account? Ok, if you did research that's fine, it's just best to demonstrate that by showing what research you did.

Comment: Good point: do you think 1099-div is the appropriate income area that I should report the the dividends from  non-US brokerage accounts?

Comment: I don't know, but I believe it is. The 1099DIV instructions should be clear enough on that part at least.

Answer (score 0):

Once has to fill a Form 1099-DIV for dividends earnt for each brokerage accounts located outside the United States. The Form 1099-DIV allows to distinguish ordinary dividends from qualified dividends, and is also used for reporting dividends for brokerage accounts located *inside* the United States.

https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3181561-how-to-report-dividends-from-a-foreign-brokerage-account-when-there-is-no-1099-div gives some interesting information ([mirror](http://archive.is/iCzWY)):

> > **Question**: Do I report the dividends on the "Dividends on 1099-DIV" section? I looked at this section but it asks for the boxes on the 1099-DIV which I don't have.
>
> **Answer**: Yes - please use the data entry as if you received Form 1099-DIV
>
> > **Question**: As for converting EUR to USD: Should I convert the amounts using the exchange rate at the date I received the dividend or the exchange rate at the end of the year?
>
> **Answer**: Use the exchange rate when you receive the dividend (or for foreign tax paid, if any, use the rate when you pay/accrue the tax)
>
> > **Question**: As for converting EUR to USD: What service should I use to get the exchange rate?
>
> **Answer**:  please use the following link; scroll down...it lists government sources as well as outside sources for exchange rates:
>
> - https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Foreign-Currency-and-Currency-Exchange-Rates   ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190407200313/https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-currency-and-currency-exchange-rates))
> - Additional information: https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Yearly-Average-Currency-Exchange-Rates ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190407200313/https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-currency-and-currency-exchange-rates))

(Questions by Mike, anwsers by "TurboTaxMargaretL, Enrolled Agent")